# Require certain address in HTML form

Tags: html, forms

I have a site where people can submit YouTube videos.

What I need help with (not being very good at HTML programming) is that some use it to post spam or malformed URLS.

What I have is a HTML form with a text box and a button.

So I need it so people can only submit of they have entered a URL to a YouTube page in the form of "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" Then their video ID.

Basically I only want them to be able to submit "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" with their video ID on the end, EG, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qLTrO60o3E

Hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Thank you.
Jack,

Comment: You need to implement the validation serverside, not just clientside.

Comment: This can easily be done with a scripting language like PHP. I'm not sure this is possible with just HTML/Forms.

Comment: The first rule of internet forms is: *do* ***not*** *trust the users*. ***Ever***. Validate client-side (with JavaScript) for user-convenience, and then validate server-side, before entry into the database, for security. Oh, and why not just have them enter a video id, rather than a full URL?

Comment: David I have wanted to do this. Did not know that this should/could not be this way. Could you show me how you would do this?

Comment: Look at [`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) and [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). These are, of course, PHP filters (using [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). But as @DavidThomas said, you have to validate and verify everything user give you in forms and online in general.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the URL via a regular expression to check whether it is in a given format. You could implement this on the client side, but as posted in the question comments any input must also be checked on the server. It's easy for a user to disable JavaScript and most Spam bots doesn't even use JavaScript.

For modern browsers, the client-side implementation could be done as easily as using the [HTML5 form validation `pattern` attribute](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2011/03/14/html5-form-validation-on-sumo/) with a regular expression. So yes, this can be done using plain HTML (well, not for IE).

Following examples are regular expressions for JavaScript from the [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) [mediahtml5 plugin](http://www.cjboco.com/projects.cfm/project/tinymce-html5-media-plug-in/0.0.1):

```
YouTube
/watch\?v=(.+)(.*)/

Vimeo
/vimeo\.com\/(.+)/

Dailymotion
/dailymotion\.com\/video\/([^_]*)/
```